# Postfix + MySQL - Problem with GRANT command

Tags: server, mysql, postfix

I am trying to install on Ubuntu Server 16.10:

- Postfix
- MySQL
- ClamAV
- Amavis
- Dovecot

I am using those tutorials:
https://blogging.dragon.org.uk/installing-a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-part-1/#comment-278

https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

But after:

```
GRANT SELECT ON postfix.* TO mail@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mysqlpasswd';
```

or any variation of `GRANT` command, I am getting that command has been done successfully, but 0 rows were changed and 1 error occurred, but don't know which one.

Any help please? Should I just go on or this error is a major thing?

Answer (score 0):

To view the mysql statement errors, please execute below mysql statement immediately after executing your grant statement :

```
mysql> SHOW ERRORS;
```

Ref : Please visit the following link for more information http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-errors.html